# Convert date/month/year string variable to include time

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following data with some Date/Month/Year string values:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'date': ["31/03/2019", "12/05/2020"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

print(df)

date
0  31/03/2019
1  12/05/2020`
```

I would like the `date` variable to be printed like this:

```
new_d = {'date': ["2019-03-31T00:00:000Z", "2020-05-12T00:00:000Z"]}
correct_df = pd.DataFrame(data=new_d)

print(correct_df)
```

So the format is `"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ"`. Does anyone know how I would go about achieving this? I have read numerous articles on how to strip date/month/year and reorder, but not how to include time. The inclusion of time here will always be 'T00:00:000Z' as the original value does not contain time. This is for aesthetic reasons only.

I think this can be done with a function like below but it doesn't quite work for me:

```
def convert_to_json_date(incoming_string: str)-> str:
     return incoming_string as ("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=True).dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
```

Output:

```
0    2019-03-31T00:00:00.000000Z
1    2020-05-12T00:00:00.000000Z
Name: date, dtype: object
```